# How to access a samba share from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

I have a tiny retro console and I can activate the samba share. On windows it's extremely easy to connect, I just put //hostname on the file browser and it works, and I can transfer games from windows to the console.

On Ubuntu I cannot make it work. I don't have samba, but I was expecting to be as easy as on windows from the file manager. Any way I can just have as a location on the File Manager on Ubuntu. And I can't use samba on Ubuntu.
Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly can you not use samba on Ubuntu. I certainly have in the past

Comment: I have tried but always same erro, you have held broken packages. The question, is do I need samba for that? Can't I do like on windows just from the file manager?

Comment: You need to fix the APT issue first. And yes, you need samba.

Comment: Why not just SMB://windowsmachineorIP/folder  ?  I have connected that way just now. Make sure the folder on Windows has a share setting on it.

Comment: The shared folder is from a linux machine using samba, but from another ubuntu I can't access, from windows I just do //hostname and magically works. And I tried SMB://ip and SMB://ip/hostname from connect to network in Ubuntu File Manager but it does not work.

Comment: So then you will need Samba to share from Linux to Linux.  Maybe try another avenue to install Samba,

Comment: You don't *need* ***samba*** persay.  You only need the samba client package (smbclient).  Once you have the smbclient package, [you can even create a mount point](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050460/how-to-mount-smb-share-on-ubuntu-18-04) in Ubuntu making the rest seamless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely share the same folder that you're sharing with SAMBA with NFS at the same time. If it was me I would fix the SAMBA issue, but you have the option.

Windows only works that way because explorer has a working SMB protocol and right now your Linux client doesn't.

Comment: This is clear, thank you. Unfortunately I tried a million times fixing samba, but the end solution is reinstalling Ubuntu and I can't afford that. Is there an explorer on Ubuntu/Linux that has the smb client built-in?

Comment: Not actually in the file manager as far as I'm aware. But KDE has kioslaves for it's konqueror browser/file manager. It would access smb through the package kio-fuse. This may require the smbclient package! I assume when you say you can't use samba that it's because you can't install smbclient or it is broken. Gnome uses smbclient and I'm only saying it's possible  KDE doesn't, but it very well might. If you try it be aware Konqueror and kio-fuse packages may bring in a lot of dependencies!!

Comment: It appears it might work based on https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/kio-fuse and that smb is supposedly in the kernel. Also you may want to install dolphin instead of Konqueror if you try it. You can run Dolphin or Konqueror inside of your existing window manager without otherwise using kde.